# Placing 2D arrays onto a larger 2D array, ensuring neat placement

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to wrap my head around this problem for weeks now, and haven't been able to come up with a reasonable solution.

## The overall problem

Given a 2D array (say `grid`) and an array of (hopefully smaller) 2D arrays (say `groups`), I need to arrange each `group` within the `grid` in a manner that roughly preserves ordering (if `A` is next to `B` in `groups`, they should be near each other when placed on `grid`).

For example, placing the following groups onto a 3x3 grid

```
A A
```

```
B
B
```

```
C
```

Would result in

```
A A -
B C -
B - -
```

## Placement direction

I also need to be able to specify the direction in which they are placed.

The above example demonstrates left-to-right, top-to-bottom placement. Placing the same items bottom-to-top, left-to-right would result in the following placement:

```
B - -
B C -
A A -
```

Note that placement direction shouldn't affect the layout of the groups. For example, placing

```
A1 A2
A3 A4
```

In a 3x3 grid using right-to-left, bottom-to-top would result in

```
-  -  -
-  A1 A2
-  A3 A4
```

## Truncation

As well as this, there may be cases where a group is given that cannot fit inside `group`. In these cases, we must either truncate or wrap that item. What to do is specified before the algorithm runs, but it should handle both cases.

For example, if we wanted to place `A A A A` onto a 3x2 grid and truncate any parts that don't fit, the result would be

```
A A A
- - -
```

The direction to truncate is also specified before running the algorithm: for example, truncating from the top left when placing

```
A1 A2 A3
A4 A5 A6
A7 A8 A9
```

onto a 2x2 grid would result in

```
A5 A6
A8 A9
```

Truncation should not occur unless it is impossible to fit the entire group anywhere in the `grid`.

For example, if placing `A A` and `B B` on a 3x2 grid, we would get

```
A A -
B B -
```

and not

```
A A B
- - -
```

## Wrapping

If we want to wrap larger groups instead of truncating them, these groups should be on their own row so that we don't separate a group beyond reason.

For example, instead of

```
A A B B
B B B -
- - - -
```

We would prefer

```
A A - -
B B B B
B - - -
```

Of course, like with truncation, we shouldn't wrap a group unless it is absolutely necessary.

For example, instead of

```
A A B B
B B - -
```

We would prefer

```
A A - -
B B B B
```

### Wrapping directions

Both of the above examples of wrapping are for a left-to-right, top-to-bottom direction.

- When filling `grid` horizontally first (eg "left-to-right, top-to-bottom"), groups that are too tall should be truncated - only the width is wrapped.
- When filling `grid` vertically first (eg "top-to-bottom, left-to-right"), groups that are too wide should be truncated - only the height is wrapped.

A group that is being wrapped should be sliced along the primary direction, with the second slice placed in the next position in the secondary direction.

For example, if the direction is top-to-bottom, right-to-left, attempting to place

```
A1
A2
A3
```

on a 2x2 grid would give

```
A3 A1
-  A2
```

### Wrapping larger groups

If a group is larger, it should be wrapped whilst maintaining the integrity of the secondary direction.

For example, placing

```
A1 A2 A3 A4
A5 A6 A7 A8
```

onto a 3x4 grid would produce

```
A1 A2 A3
A5 A6 A7
A4 -  -
A8 -  -
```

## What do I do?

As you've probably guessed, this problem is extremely complex. As such, I'm not necessarily expecting a full solution to it. What I am looking for instead is a collection of smaller problems that I can tackle which can be combined to create a full solution to the overall problem.

I don't need my overall solution to be amazingly performant, as the `grid` is unlikely to be greater than 10x10, and will likely only run once every few seconds during my application's runtime.

Thanks for bearing with me

Comment: Which is your issue? I expect you already have though about working group by group and searching for its place that satisfies conditions, even by brute-force. Can you move a previously inserted group? If so, that's a lot of more work.

Comment: @Ripi2 my main problem is that I'm struggling to generalise it - I have gotten implementations working that account for individual features, but I can't wrap my head around getting it to work for everything at once. In particular, handling the direction option has been a challenge: I haven't been able to find a way to incorporate it without writing essentially the same code 4 times.

Comment: It seems that sometimes there can be several valid solutions. Then this is a combinatorial problem. If any one is good for you then go ahead and use brute-force for each group insertion.

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge to handle the directions, rotate and flip the grid, not the placement. So let's say you have a solution which works for placing from top to bottom, left to right. If you want to place from bottom to top instead, then fill the board as you normally would and then just flip the y coordinates.

Comment: So, basically bin-packing, but with more complex corner cases?

Comment: @Maurycyt sadly flipping the grid doesn't work since that would mess with the ordering of the groups being placed (they could be backwards or upside down).

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge you're right, I didn't notice that. But isn't that easily fixed? First fill the grid as usual, then perform the transformations, and then, since you already know which elements belong to which groups and the original dimensions of each group and whether to truncate or wrap them, renumbering the elements according to some simple rule should work. Say you have the 2x2 truncation example. Perform the algorithm and make the grid transformation, you get A8 A9 // A5 A6, but all that matters are the As. Then renumber them to get A5 A6 // A8 A9 because you know the direction & sizes.

Comment: If the first example, why is "B B" not placed in the third column, which would be consistent with left-to-right (first) and (only then) top-to-bottom orders? Similarly I don't understand what it is not place in the third column for the example under "Placement direction". In the example given under "Wrapping directions", why is A3 not placed in the top-left corner? This is what I would expect with top-to-bottom ordering...

Comment: Are there any cases where -- to avoid wrapping/truncating -- items are placed in a different order than originally given? In other words, does the algorithm need *backtracking*?

Comment: @Maurycyt oh smart! This definitely sounds like it'd simplify things a bunch!

Comment: @trincot doing that would result in either leaving extra blank space and putting C on the third row, or having the ordering be less clear. I know the logic is a little flimsy - the main thing is it doesn't need to be perfect, just close enough, so doing that would also be a valid solution.

Comment: @trincot no, the order should be preserved - if we need to prevent truncation or wrapping, we should just leave some space and start again on the next line.

Comment: *"doing that would result in either leaving extra blank space and putting C on the third row"*: I don't understand why this would put C on the third row, nor what the extra blank space is about. What about the case about A3 that I mentioned in my earlier comment?

Comment: @trincot I imagine your suggestion re C on the third row would result in either `A A B / C - B / - - -` (ordering is less clear) or `A A B / - - B / C - -` (lots of empty space). For the A3 case, that was a typo, your assumption was correct and I've edited the post to reflect it.

Comment: I would have expected the first. How shall we measure whether an order is *clear* or not?

Comment: I don't have any strict criteria for it, so it can be flexible. The main thing is not to have things all over the place, or clearly out of order. Anything that looks reasonable is good enough for me.

Comment: Since you don't care about performance, just write a brute-force algorithm for the plethora of rules you decided to introduce. Overall, this many poorly defined rules tends to indicate a poor understanding of what it is that you *actually* want, this sounds like you are solving a subproblem of a larger problem you likely don't have to solve, if you understood the big picture better.